# Probability of a point being sampled from multiple gaussians.

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

Given two gassuian distributions, $g_1(\mu_1,\sigma_1)$ and $g_2(\mu_2,\sigma_2)$ and a point $x$ now we need to find the probability of $x$ being sampled from $g_1$ versus $g_2$. I thought of simply comparing their pdfs at that point $x$ but my friend said that it would give wrong result and we need to find conditional probabilities to estimate it.

I don't understand how can we do that.

Comment: Is $x$ equally likely to have come from either distribution (a priori)?

Comment: @MikeEarnest yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be the observation, and let $E$ be the event that $X$ was chosen from $g_1$. Using Bayes' theorem:
$$
P(E|X=x)=\frac{P(X=x|E)\cdot P(E)}{P(X=x|E)\cdot P(E)+P(X=x|E^c)\cdot P(E^c)}
$$
If we interpret the above fraction literally, it would be $\frac00$, since $X$ is a continuous random variable. However, if we let $P(X=x|E)$ denote the conditional density of $X$ given $E$ has occurred, then the above is correct. I will let you fill in the details.

Comment: Hey @Mike can you explain why the above question becomes right when we use $P(X=x|E)$ or can you answer my question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723260/shouldnt-the-probability-of-sampling-a-point-from-a-continuous-distribution-be?noredirect=1#comment7653397_3723260

Comment: And suppose there was only one Gaussian distribution $g_1$ then how could you find the probability of $x$ being sampled from $g_1$? Wouldn't that be zero?